# Images not showing on cloudflare pages

Tags: node.js, three.js, cloudflare, vite

I have created a THREE.js app using vite and node. When I am in my dev environment everything works perfectly, however, when I deployed this to Cloudflare pages using:
`vite build` 
as my build command. The textures (images) are not showing but the shaders are. I am deploying it to cloudflare from github.

I am getting no errors in the browser console and no errors in the build log. Here is my folder structure

```
-images
-shaders
main.js
package-lock.json
package.json
style.css
vite.config.css
```

My Vite config file looks like this:

```
import vitePluginString from 'vite-plugin-string'

export default {
    plugins: [
        vitePluginString()
    ],
    build: {
        chunkSizeWarningLimit: 2048 // 2kb
    }
}
```

The build option is to prevent a warning I was getting about chunk size but it makes no difference if I take it out, I thought that could have been the problem. Any help is much appreciated thanks!

This is the code I am using to import the assets.

```
function createMoon(radius, orbit, speed){
  const moon = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 10, 16), new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: moonVertexShader,
    fragmentShader: moonFragmentShader,
    uniforms: {
      moonTexture: {
        value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('./images/moon.jpg')
      }
    },
  }));
```

This code works fine on local dev server.

Comment: From what you are showing of your directory tree structure, and without knowing how you are importing assets, I am tempted to say that you are missing something about importing them. Could you add more details, code ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply I added the code to show how I am importing the assets in the project. This works fine on local dev server/

Answer (score 1):

I put the images folder in another folder named public and removed the ./ where the images were being loaded in the code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Ecburt's answer, if you aren't seeing your static assets in while using cloudflare pages, rename the folder containing your assets to `public` and update all exist file paths to point to this new folder.

Old project structure:

```
project
 - assets
   - foo.png
 - src
 - index.html
...

---
<img src="./assets/foo.png" alt="foo">
```

New project structure:

```
project
 - public
   - foo.png
 - src
 - index.html
...

---
<img src="./public/foo.png" alt="foo">
```

If you are using `Vite` you do not need to use `public` in the path name:

`<img src="/foo.png" alt="foo">`